# Gson().fromJson() throws com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException

Tags: android, firebase, gson

I am developing an Android application using Firebase FireStore Database.

When my application read data, Firebase returns below Json data.

```
{email=topofsan@naver.com, name=DennisNaver, comment=Test profile for Dennis Naver account, imageUrl=None}
```

And I am using below Kotlin code to parse Json data.

```
val profile = Gson().fromJson(task.result.data.toString(), Profile::class.java)
```

Then Gson throw below error message.

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unterminated object at line 1 column 60 path $.comment
```

The data class Profile is defined as below.

```
data class Profile(var imageUrl: String, var email: String, var name: String, var comment: String)
```

I modified Json data as below and tried parse it using Gson. Then it worked.

```
{email=“topofsan@naver.com”, name=“DennisNaver”, comment=“Test profile for Dennis Naver account”, imageUrl=“None”}
```

How can I fix is issue?

Comment: The above response has the following problems:
1. Keys should have "". For instance email => "email"
2. There should be a colon delimiter and not "="

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is self answer.
I fixed this issue by using both Gson().toJson() & Gson().fromJson()

```
val json = Gson().toJson(task.result.data)
val profile = Gson().fromJson(json, Profile::class.java)
```

Comment: To explain why that fixes the issue: What you have shown in your question was not JSON data, it was the output of `toString()`, more specifically `task.result.data.toString()` which you passed to Gson. Unfortunately Gson is lenient by default, see the [`Gson` class documentation](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/Gson.html), section "Lenient JSON handling", which is why it might accept such data (e.g. after you added quotes), but you should not rely on that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix your data.  The initial version is not JSON.  JSON requires the quotes.  Without those, it's impossible for the parser to know where one value ends and the next begins.  I don't know what put the data into your db, but that process is broken.B